# Using DateTime in Livecharts WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datetime, livecharts

I have created a CartesianChart using LiveCharts in WPF which shows values from a list called NIOquoteTrend. The list is populated with values from a database and each value has a specific corresponding timestamp in the database.

I have displayed the values with intervals of 1 hour and I have a DateTimePicker to specify the timestamps between which the values will be shown. There is also a button which then calls the funcion UpdateQuoteTrend(). The values are displayed correctly in the chart but what I do not know how to do is how to display the DateTime in the x-Axis corresponding to the specific value.

Since the series-values are displayed correctly and in the right order I think a solution would be to just display the dates and times between the selected values as labels in the X-Axes  with an interval of 1 hour. If anyone has any idea how I could do that I would very much appreciate the help. 
Below is my cs code:

```
    void UpdateQuoteTrend()
    {

        if (trendChart.Series.Count > 0)
            trendChart.Series.Clear();

        trendChart.Series.Add(new LineSeries
        {
            Title = "Fehlerquote",
            Values = NIOquoteTrend.AsChartValues(),
            Stroke = Brushes.Red,
            PointGeometry = DefaultGeometries.Circle,
            PointGeometrySize = 15
        });
    }
```

This is my XAML code:

```
    <Wpf:CartesianChart x:Name="trendChart" Margin="0,40,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  LegendLocation="Right" FontSize="20" Zoom="Xy" ScrollMode="XY" >
        <Wpf:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <Wpf:Axis x:Name="xAxisTrendChart" Title="Datum" FontSize="20" />
        </Wpf:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    </Wpf:CartesianChart>
```

and this is what the graph looks like:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hnVU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I solved it. I just created a new SQL Query/ Stored Procedure similar to the one I used to get the values from the database, just instead of values I get the timestamps as string. I then save the timestamps in a list which I use as labels in my x-Axis.